# Attempt to present on ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is the code used on the main menu, when the user presses play, however when that screen is presented (ViewController.m) it shows the error

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    if(IS_IPAD)
    {
        ViewController *view_obj = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentViewController:view_obj animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else if ([AISGlobal isIphone5thGeneration])
    {
        ViewController *view_obj = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentViewController:view_obj animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
    else
    {
        ViewController *view_obj = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentViewController:view_obj animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```

In the AppDelegate.m file it shows this in the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' section;

```
if(IS_IPAD)
    {
         self.start_screen_obj = [[Start_screen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Start_screen" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if ([AISGlobal isIphone5thGeneration])
    {
        self.start_screen_obj = [[Start_screen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Start_screen_iphone5" bundle:nil];

    }
    else
    {
       self.start_screen_obj = [[Start_screen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Start_screen_iphone" bundle:nil];
    }

    self.start_screen_obj.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.start_screen_obj;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: The error explains exactly what is going on. You are presenting a UIViewController onto the view hierarchy from a UIViewController that currently is not part of the view hierarchy. You haven't posted enough context for us to be able to help you debug the issue.

Comment: I am launching the method that cannot be presented, from the ViewController.m file, which is presented when the user presses Play on the Start screen, I cannot see where-else to place it, if I try to do it when the user presses play, it still presents same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the presenting view controller (i.e. `self`) is not added as child view controller. 
You can workaround that warning by presenting your vc on `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController` instead of `self`

Comment: Hi @arturdev whereabouts am I placing this? in the Appdelegate or when calling the View after pressing play?

Comment: everywhere when you calling `[self presentViewController:...`

Answer (score 3):

Try to write your code in view controllers viewDidAppear method because till that time your view is just created not added in view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**This is example of FormAlertView using Swift 2.3**

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var loginTextField: UITextField?
    var passwordTextField: UITextField?
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "UIAlertController", message: "UIAlertController With TextField", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Ok Button Pressed")
    })
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
        print("Cancel Button Pressed")
    }
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
        // Enter the textfiled customization code here.
        loginTextField = textField
        loginTextField?.placeholder = "User ID"
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
        // Enter the textfiled customization code here.
        passwordTextField = textField
        passwordTextField?.placeholder = "Password"
        //            passwordTextField?.secureTextEntry = true
    }

    //        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    //          present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

*You can easily to copy paste in your project viewController  and run.*